# What is the word for all food eaten

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I'd like to know what is the word to describe all the food eaten by a person at a dinner or restaurant. I think *recipe* is all the food cooked in a dinner, not the exact fit.

Comment: How do you intend to use this word?  It seems "food" in context would work

Comment: Would _serving_ or _portion_ be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recipe** is the ingredients and instructions for cooking the food. I think **meal** would be a better fit for what you're looking for: it would encompass all the food the diner eats at a particular time/in one sitting.